# chrome webRequest throwing error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i am writing chrome extension that can log all HTTP request, just like the requests in network tab in your console window.

the manifest file as follow

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Youtube Controls",
    "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser action with kittens.",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_scripts":[{
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
        "js":["youtube.js"]
    }],
    "background":{
        "scripts": ["wb.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "youtube.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

youtube.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        greeting: 'hello'
    });
});
```

wb.js (background script)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, response){
    console.log(request);
    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
        console.log(details);
    },{
        urls: ["<all_urls>"]
    });
});
```

if i remove the `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addLister()` i can see the console.log is working, but if the webRequest script is there, it is throwing error in the console. here is the error:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://ammnjfgoofnjeoglmbhbeijmmnmfjbdk/popup.js:13:30
    at disconnectListener (extensions::messaging:335:9)
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:397:22)
    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:93:26)
    at EventImpl.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:379:35)
    at EventImpl.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:403:17)
    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatch] (extensions::utils:93:26)
    at dispatchOnDisconnect (extensions::messaging:290:27) extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:9
```

what is the problem? how to fix it?